# Need help in determining the time complexity of a function

Tags: c++, time-complexity

This is the function I used for solving [removing duplicate elements from a string](https://practice.geeksforgeeks.org/problems/recursively-remove-all-adjacent-duplicates/0). I am unable to figure out its time complexity.

What is its time complexity?

```
inline string removedup(string s){
    int n = s.length();
    if(n == 1)
        return s;
    int i = 1;
    string str;
    if(s[0] != s[1])
        str.push_back(s[0]);
    while(i < n){
        if(s[i] == s[i - 1]);
        else if(i < n-1 and s[i] == s[i+1]);
        else
            str.push_back(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    if(str.length() == 0)
        return str;
    if(str.length() != n)
        return removedup(str);
    return str;
}
```

Comment: @TonyTannous Calling the `removedup(str)` will not add up to the runtime?

Comment: Each call is O(string-length). Read [Bog O notation](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation) and [Best, worst and average case](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Best,_worst_and_average_case) and [Asymptotic analysis](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Asymptotic_analysis) on wikipedia.

Comment: @TonyTannous Got it. Thanks.

Comment: In worst case (`"abcdeffedcba"`), it is quadratic.

Comment: Eh I just noticed a recursive call. Sorry for giving an incorrect answer. Indeed, for a string where you only skip the first character before the while loop, and none more in the loop, it will take quadratic complexity.

Answer (score 0):

The time complexity will `O(n^2)`

```
inline string removedup(string s){
    int n = s.length();
    if(n == 1)
        return s;
    int i = 1;
    string str;
    if(s[0] != s[1])
        // This is O(1)
        str.push_back(s[0]);

    // This operation will be O(n)
    while(i < n){
        if(s[i] == s[i - 1]);
        else if(i < n-1 and s[i] == s[i+1]);
        else
            str.push_back(s[i]);
        i++;
    }
    if(str.length() == 0)
        return str;

    // This will again be O(n)
    if(str.length() != n)
        return removedup(str);
    return str;
}
```